# MySQL Date Type in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date

I have a mySQL database and some tables and one table contains a column that is of Type DATE. I've put in some dates like `2015-12-28` or `2015-12-29`. Now, when I query this table within my Node app.js, the rows returned aren't exactly in the same format, instead of `2015-12-28` the rows return `Mon Dec 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)` - this is rather annoying and I don't know what would be the smartest approach to get javascript (Node) to give me the same Date format I have put inside my database. I need to make inserts in a different table, which also has a column of Date type, but since the fetched Javascript row doesn't match to `2015-12-28` my insert doesn't work. Which is obvious, since it is containing the wrong information. Could someone point me in the right direction or maybe some example code or reference?

thank you.

Comment: Try   new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');

Comment: wow... I've just asked this question, I thought to myself I should try the javascript Date Object Methods. Yup, you guessed it, `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()` and `getDate()` returned the information I was looking for. I will continue using these Object Methods, I guess this is a good approach.

Comment: @devpro I was just typing my comment so I didn't see yours, I will also try your solution and see what works best for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yes two solution one is yurs second is yurs